# cohomology ring of cross-section space of fibre-bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, sheaf-cohomology, local-cohomology

Given an $m$-dimensional manifold $M$, let $TM$ be the tangent bundle of $M$ and $SM$ be the $m$-sphere bundle over $M$ obtained by fibre-wise one point compactification of $TM$. Let $\Gamma(SM)$ be the space of cross-sections of $SM$ equipped with compact-open topology. Suppose the cohomology ring $H^*(M)$ is known. How to compute the cohomology ring
$$
H^*(\Gamma(SM);\mathbb{Z}_p)
$$
for primes $p\geq 2$?

Comment: Some thoughts: This seems really hard. To get a feel for this, it might be a good idea to start with $M=S^3$. As the tangent bundle is trivial, this space equals $Map(S^3\rightarrow S^3)$. How to compute the homology of such a space? One can probably write down fibrations, similar to the pathspace and loop space fibrations, and get serre spectral sequence converging to the cohomology of the based space of maps $Map_*(S^3,S^3)$, and the unbased one $Map(S^3,S^3)$ respectively. I have never done such computations though...